Proving the identity: $f^{-1}(a,\infty)=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k=m}^\infty f_k^{-1}\left(a+\frac{1}{j},\infty\right)$

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{S})$ is a measurable space and $f_1,f_2,\cdots$ is a sequence of $\mathcal{S}$-measurable functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}f_k(x)=f(x)$ exists for each $x\in X$. Then $f$ is an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function.

The key idea of the proof is the following identity, I'm trying to convince myself that $$f^{-1}(a,\infty)=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k=m}^\infty f_k^{-1}\left(a+\frac{1}{j},\infty\right)$$
I tried to expand the right-hand-side, which looks like \begin{align}
&(f_{1}^{-1}(a+1,\infty)\cap f_2^{-1}(a+1,\infty)\cap \cdots)\bigcup (f_{2}^{-1}(a+1,\infty)\cap f_3^{-1}(a+1,\infty)\cap \cdots)\bigcup\cdots\\ & \left(f_{1}^{-1}\left(a+\frac{1}{2},\infty\right)\cap f_2^{-1}\left(a+\frac{1}{2},\infty\right)\cap \cdots\right)\bigcup \left(f_{2}^{-1}\left(a+\frac{1}{2},\infty\right)\cap f_3^{-1}\left(a+\frac{1}{2},\infty\right) \cdots\right)
\end{align}
Suppose that $x\in \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k=m}^\infty f_k^{-1}\left(a+\frac{1}{j},\infty\right)$, then there exist some $k,j\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$x\in f_k^{-1}\left(a+\frac{1}{j},\infty\right)\bigcap f_{k+1}\left(a+\frac{1}{j},\infty\right)\bigcap \cdots$$
which implies that $f_N(x)>a+\frac{1}{j}$ for all $N\geq k$. Since $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty} f_k(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in X$, $$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N_1\in\mathbb{N}, s.t.\ \forall k\geq N_1, \vert f_k(x)-f(x)\vert<\epsilon$$
Choose $N_2=\max\{N,N_1\}$ and $\epsilon=\frac{1}{j}$, then $$f(x)>f_k(x)-\frac{1}{j}>a, \forall k\geq N_2 \implies x\in f^{-1}(a,\infty)$$
On the other hand, if $x\in f^{-1}(a,\infty)$, then $f(x)>a$. Thus, $f(x)>a+\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$(Archimedean Property). I prove this by contradiction:
If there does not exist such $k$ and $j$, then $f_k(x)\leq a$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$. By choosing $\epsilon =\frac{1}{n}$, we have $$f(x)<f_k(x)+\frac{1}{n}\leq a+\frac{1}{n}$$
which contradicts to the fact that $f(x)>a+\frac{1}{n}$.
My Question: The author just gives the identity without explanation. Is that obvious, or is there a simpler proof? I have encountered some identities similar to this in measure theory. It seems that it is very important to realize such an identity in a short time. How can I convince myself (or construct such an identity by myself) as it seems really not obvious to me. Thanks in advance:)

Let $x \in \text{LHS}$. This means that $f(x) > a$ and so there exists a $j \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x) > a + \frac{1}{j}$ by the Archimedean property. As $f_k(x) \rightarrow f(x)$, there exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k \ge m$, $f_k(x) > a + \frac{1}{j}$. So $x \in \bigcap_{k=m}^{\infty}f_k^{-1}(a+ \frac{1}{j}, \infty)$ and so $x \in \text{RHS}$.
Now take $x \in \text{RHS}$. There exist $j, m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k \ge m$, $f_k(x) > \alpha + \frac{1}{j}$. As $k \rightarrow \infty$, $f(x) > \alpha + \frac{1}{j} > \alpha$. So $x \in f^{-1}(\alpha, \infty)$ and therefore $x \in \text{LHS}$.
So $\text{LHS} = \text{RHS}$.

Thank you for your attempt! Really succinct :)
